# "these functions are strictly non-decreasing, whereas the others ARE", or "these functions are strictly non-decreasing, whereas the others DO"?

Tags: negation, be, do

Should I say

```
 "these functions are strictly non-decreasing, whereas the others ARE.", 
 - or - 
 "these functions are strictly non-decreasing, whereas the others DO." ?
```

Related, but not similar:

```
 "these kids in the video are clearly not playing, whereas the others ARE.", 
 - or - 
 "these kids in the video are clearly not playing, whereas the others DO."
```

Which is correct in each example, and what is the difference?

Thanks!

Comment: The first two examples are ungrammatical. A reduction too far. I couldn't rate (3) as ungrammatical, but it's clumsy. I wouldn't accept (4).

Comment: The point being, @user16etc, that the verbs need to match; *are* doesn't go with *do*. In the first examples, you have *are...whereas...are,* which won't do because *whereas* must introduce a contrast and you need "whereas...are not" -- and that is awkward because of the negative introduced in *non-decreasing.*

Comment: The first two examples simply don't make sense.

Comment: "These functions are non-decreasing, whereas the others are" seems bad, but "These functions are not decreasing, whereas the others are" seems OK.

Comment: I'll add that in the first sentence, it should be *whereas the others AREN'T [strictly non-decreasing]*. If you use *whereas* in this way, what follows should be the *opposite* of what came before.

Comment: @ Jason Bassford     Yes, actually I think that your comment makes the most sense. "Non-decreasing" is adjective in this sense, so the opposite of "are non-decreasing" is "aren't non-decreasing". Thanks! What about the second example? Here, "not playing" is not an adjective like "non-...", this is why I mentioned it is different.

Comment: @GEdgar     The meaning is different. "Not decreasing" refers to their state,  whereas "non-decreasing" is a mathematical term which defines their class, like "non-European".

Comment: You need to match auxiliary verbs: These kids in the video clearly *aren't* playing, 
whereas the others *are*; these kids in the video *don't* play fair, whereas the others *do*; these kids in the video clearly *can't* play quietly, whereas the others *can*.

Comment: @PeterShor     Thanks, I understand now.

Comment: And if there are no auxiliary verbs, and the main verb isn't *to be* or *to have*, use *do*. (The main verb *have* usually gets replaced by *do* in the U.S., but often stays as *have* in the U.K.)